# Fast Artificial Neural Network Library : FANN Error 10

Tags: static-libraries, fann

I'm using the FANN lib and when I use the fann_train_on_file function on my training file I get the following error :

```
FANN Error 10: Error reading info from train data file "/tmp/train.dat", line: 154.
```

This is the concerned file : http://pastebin.com/WvruFrXr

I'm using GNULinux/Debian Jessie with libfann2 (2.1.0~beta~dfsg-8) and libfann-dev (2.1.0~beta~dfsg-8) packages.

Comment: Your input file has incorrect format, show your input file and we can provide with help. As the error says the function cant read the input in the line 154 which means something is wrong maybe an invalid character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file was openned by another process.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it's a problem with your EOL character. Take a look of this document and switch EOL character to LF

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/

You can use a text editor and find replace to do the same

Comment: Already tried it. I think it's not a problem with the training file. Because the file works with FannTool 1.1.

Comment: yes sometimes there's extra space before the jump of line,  or even a weird encoding character instead of space it can look like a space and it causes the error

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is very old, but I found that the problem was that I wasnt appending a proper new line character to the end of my training document, kind of what has been said above, except I simply wrote to file at the end sr.write(Environment.NewLine);

This fixed it for me!